# Are US citizens required to have a US bank account to receive Social Security while living abroad?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, social-security, working-abroad, russia

My daughter and I are US citizens and we reside in Moscow, RF. My former wife and the mother of my daughter died recently. She was a  US citizen and was living in the USA. Due to her mother's loss, my daughter is eligible for a SS pension.

According to SS administrators,  in order to get the pension, I must have a US bank account because the pension funds can only be transferred to the account of a legal guardian.  I do not  have any US banking accounts nor am I a current US resident.

Is there a way to settle the issue of receiving the funds and avoid my having to go to the USA to physically apply and open a bank  account?

Comment: Hi, Maksim. Could you clear up one point, please? You say you're a US citizen, but that you don't have US residency. Do you perhaps mean that you don't have a US residential address?

Comment: To Rupert Morrish: Yes, this is exactly what I meant by saying that I don't have a residency. I do not have a residential address in the USA.

Comment: It may be worth a visit to some banks that have a presence in both countries (HSBC seem to, not sure if there are others) and seeing if they can help.

Comment: See the Social Security Administration's booklet [Your Payments While You Are Outside the United States](https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10137.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Social Security Administration's FAQ](https://faq.ssa.gov/en-us/Topic/article/KA-02537), there is no general requirement to have your funds deposited in a US-based bank; you just need to live in a country where the SSA can send benefits. A quick glance suggests [Russia is one of those countries](https://www.ssa.gov/international/countrylist6.htm), so I would contact the SSA to figure out the details of setting up such internationals deposits.